# username before @

Tags: regex

I want to match the username before `@` in address mail, 
and i create this regex

```
[A-Za-z+ /w+0-9._%+-]+@
```

the result of my example is:

```
example:  blabla,blabla,Test@Testing.com,blabla,blabla,blabla
result : Test@
```

How can I get only `Test` without `@`.

Comment: Turn `@` into a lookahead - `(?=@)` (like [`[\w /.%+-]+(?=@)`](https://regex101.com/r/mqvRGM/1)). Or enclose the whole pattern before `@` with `(` and `)` and get the `res[1]` value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew damn, you're fast!

Comment: What is the regex flavor/programming language?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:
`([A-Za-z /0-9._%+-]+)@`
and than use at what you taken (`$1` in perl, match var in tcl, etc.)
btw,
I didn't know email addresses can have spaces in them, are you sure you're not taking too much in?

Edit:
here's a little tutorial on lookaheads (supporting Wiktor's comment)
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I suggest [testing regexps](https://regex101.com/r/V5bQJq/1). BTW, didn't it occur to you that several `+` inside a character class makes no sense? One is enough. Also, `/w` looks like a corrupt `\w`, and `\w` (depending on the regex flavor and actual requirement) might be a wrong pattern to use.

Comment: sorry, I usually test the regexp, but this time I just took the given regexp and used it blindly...  
That's what you get for answering people while at work... :)  
As to the `+/w` ect. - they only mean characters the regexp will find, even if he meant `\w+` and I'm not much of a web programmer, so I don't know what are the legal chars of an email address - I just took what he gave me.